# A question about minors of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms

Let $B_{\bar{i}\bar{i}}$ denote the remnant of a square matrix $B$ after its $i^{th}$ row and $i^{th}$ column have been removed. Now given any vector $v$ is there some natural relation between the quantities $v'^T B_{\bar{i}\bar{i}} v'$ and $v^TBv$? (where $v'$ is such that it is $v$ with its component along the $i^{th}$ coordinate is removed)

- Any inequality or an equation that can be written down amongst them?
- particularly  if $v$ has no component along the $i^{th}$ coordinate?
- do kindly state if anything strikes your mind about these expressions! (even if it doesn't directly answer the question!)

Comment: edited the typo!

Comment: It's quite hard to say anything without any extra information about $B$. I'd try something with the identity: $$x^Tx = \operatorname{Tr}(xx^T),$$
for any column vector $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

Let $b_i$ is the $i^{th}$ row of the matrix $B=\|b_{km}\|$ and $b^i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of the matrix $B$. Then
$$v'^T B_{\bar{i}\bar{i}} v'=v^TBv-v_i(v,b_i^T)-v_i(v,b^{i}) +v_i^2b_{ii}.$$ In particular, if $v_i=0$ then 
$v'^T B_{\bar{i}\bar{i}} v'=v^TBv.$

Comment: Thanks! Another variation of this which I need is the case of comparing $v'^T (B_{\bar{i} \bar{i}})^{-1} v'$  vs $v^T B^{-1} v$ and everything else remaining the same. You have any thoughts about it?

Comment: @user6818 Unfortunately, I have no ideas, because the multiplication by the inverse matrices make things messy.